# Why do we define line integrals in this way?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition, line-integrals

I'm trying to understand why the line integral over vector fields are defined as such.

From [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field): "the line integral is viewed as the trajectory of a particle (in red) along a curve inside a vector field. Starting from $a$, the particle traces the path $C$ along the vector field $F$. The dot product (green line) of its tangent vector (red arrow) and the field vector (blue arrow) defines an area under a curve, which is equivalent to the path's line integral."
[image]

So my question is why this is relevant? Why do mathematicians define line integral over vector fields in this way? Is it because this line integral is the work done by the particle?

Comment: We define it this way because it is a convenient useful tool in modeling problems. Work done by a particle is a special case of such a useful application

Comment: It would help to open any reasonable textbook on physics, for example classical mechanics. The work analogy is correct. This is a candidate model for a particle moving through a forcefield, for example water currents, electromagnetic forces, wind pressure, etc.

Comment: @gt6989b so they define it in this way because of the physical applications? it must have a pure mathematical reason to define it as such.

Comment: @user42912: Definitions don't come from thin air. They are made to be useful in the context they are applied in. It's not unreasonable to think that these definitions probably first came from physics, and were then generalized by mathematicians.

Comment: @AlexR. I know the physical applications, but it should have a pure mathematical reason to define it in this way.

Comment: please check this question [What exactly IS a line integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384844/what-exactly-is-a-line-integral)

Comment: Well, it plays nicely with the gradient theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem

which is a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus to multidimensions. 
It's also basically the same thing as the line integral in complex analysis, when you treat complex numbers as vectors. So in that way it's a pure mathematical reason.

Comment: If you know the reason from a physics standpoint, you have the reason from a mathematical standpoint, don't distinguish the two. The original intention of this integral was to compute work. However, you can derive other meaningful interpretations, which is what the mathematician does as well.